# Jump to anchor tag with shim to offset page position and change div color

Tags: html

I have a Google map with right sidebar. Search results come from a database and it displays map icons on a map with a list of names and addresses in the sidebar and it works correctly, however the list can have 100's of entries, not all are visible without scrolling the sidebar, however scrolling works fine but is tedious with 100's of data entries...

So...

I am using href # to jump to anchor tags in the sidebar when a user clicks on a map icon and this also works fine and displays (jumps to) the appropriate data entry which is wrapped in a div except that the target position that is displayed is behind my navbar which is fixed. This is because the anchor tag display position is, by default, the top of the page and I need to push the target data entry down by some 50px only when a map icon is clicked.

I can add height="50px" to a div and this pushes down the list in the sidebar to the correct position when a user clicks a map icon but the problem is it adds 50px to each entry in the list whether a user clicks a map icon or not.

So what I would ideally like to do is add a height="50px" shim (height offset) to the relevant entry so that is positioned 50px below the navbar and change it's div background color.
I have tried lots of ideas, but either the 50px shim is applied to each entry (not desired) or is ignored and also background color is ignored. I have checked out some other similar answers but they don't seem to apply because I am already using div #id and div .class. Any ideas?

```
function createMarker(point, map, infoWindow, html, CompanyName) {
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: point,
  map: map,
  icon: 'MapIcons/'+IdCategory+'.png',
  url: '#'+CompanyName,
  title: CompanyName
});
```

// The following is the sidebar

```
    side_bar_html +='<div id="' +CompanyName+ '" class="COMPANYNAME"><a href="javascript:myclick(' +(gmarkers.length-0)+ ')">' +CompanyName+ '</a></div>\n'+
    '<p align="justify" class="TEXT">' +CompanyDescription+ '</p>\n'+
    '</div>';


google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
window.location.href = this.url;
});
```

Comment: I might have misunderstood it, but you can always add more than one class or ID like so: `class="class1 class2"` or id="id1 id2 id3"`. Good luck otherwise.

Comment: Thank you Fausto - you understood correctly, I am unfamiliar with using multiple ID's on the same div. That might be the way to go. I'll experiment some more... The hard part seems to be applying the shim (offset) and color to just the relevant div and not to all the divs in the list..

Comment: I'll add it as an answer, you feel free to vote me up if you succeed :).